# How to minus result of two sum column

Tags: postgresql

I want to minus the sum of two column (expected_payment minus actual_payment).

How do I achieve that?

Thanks

Current query:

```
select

(SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
from ticket_payments
WHERE kod = '12010')
as expected_payment,

(SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
from ticket_payments
WHERE kod = '22010')
as actual_payment
```

Result

[image]

If I modify the query like this it will produce an error

```
select

(SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
from ticket_payments
WHERE kod = '12010')
as expected_payment,

(SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
from ticket_payments
WHERE kod = '22010')
as actual_payment,

expected_payment - actual_payment as balance_payment
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a subquery (the problem is that at this point you are creating the aliases, so they cannot be known at the same time/level):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a6147d5c89dc06962f8c64d11b49ada6)

```
SELECT 
    *,
    expected_payment - actual_payment AS balanced_payment
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (SELECT <YOUR CODE>) as expected_payment,
        (SELECT <YOUR CODE>) as actual_payment
) s
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a column alias on the same level where you defined it. You need to wrap that into a derived table:

```
select expected_payment, actual_payment, expected_payment - actual_payment as balance_payment
from (
  select (SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
          from ticket_payments
          WHERE kod = '12010') as expected_payment,
          (SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
          from ticket_payments
          WHERE kod = '22010') as actual_payment
) as x
```

Comment: Thanks this works and you help me to understand the reason behind the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select

(SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
from ticket_payments
WHERE kod = '12010')
as expected_payment,

(SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
from ticket_payments
WHERE kod = '22010')
as actual_payment,

(SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
from ticket_payments
WHERE kod = '12010')
-
(SELECT SUM(payment_amount) 
from ticket_payments
WHERE kod = '22010')
as sum_diff
```